# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-5.0

I have two tables - Products and ProductRelations. They are like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public IList<ProductRelation> ProductRelations { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRelation
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int RelatedProductId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("RelatedProductId")]
    public Product RelatedProduct { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error `InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Product.ProductRelations' of type 'IList<ProductRelation>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

I've never used OnModelCreating. Following the naming conventions are usually enough.

If I remove the `public Product RelatedProduct { get; set; }` from the `ProductRelation` class, the error goes away.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple collections in `Product`. Try something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProductRelation.Product)]
    public IList<ProductRelation> ProductRelationsLeft { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProductRelation.RelatedProduct)]
    public IList<ProductRelation> ProductRelationsRight { get; set; }
}
```

Also you can try next setup via fluent api, providing default relation collection parameter (`collection`):

> `collection` - The name of the collection navigation property on the other end of this relationship. If null or not specified, there is no navigation property on the other end of the relationship.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductRelation>()
     .HasOne(pt => pt.Product)
     .WithMany() // leave empty
     .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProductId)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductRelation>()
    .HasOne(pt => pt.RelatedProduct)
    .WithMany(t => t.ProductRelations)
    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RelatedProductId);
```

Comment: The InverseProperty seems to fix the error at first, but when quering `Products` I get a cycle-error. Eg. `var products = await _dbContext.Products.Include(x => x.ProductRelationsRight).ThenInclude(x => x.RelatedProduct).OrderBy(x => x.Name).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()`

It makes sense why, but is there a fix for that? Or should I make the logic different?

Comment: @Mads 1) what are you trying to get with this query? 2) please add full error 3) I would make a wild guess and say that you are actually need `Include` not `ThenInclude` - try `var products = await _dbContext.Products.Include(x => x.ProductRelationsRight).Include(x => x.RelatedProduct).OrderBy(x => x.Name).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()`

Comment: I need a list of products and for each product the related products with product data. For example I could ask for products with related products and get a sum of the related products price (not included in the Product class example).

Comment: Also, I cannot `.Include(x => x.RelatedProduct)` as this is not available in Product class.

Comment: The full error `InvalidOperationException: The Include path 'ProductRelationsRight->RelatedProduct' results in a cycle. Cycles are not allowed in no-tracking queries; either use a tracking query or remove the cycle.`

Comment: Removing `.AsNoTracking()` seems to make the query valid. Strange...

Comment: @Mads glad that it helped!